# Background color cell if sort is active

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a background color to the header cell of a table when:

- I apply some sort in that column;
- I apply a filter in that column.

It is possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes you can apply background color to a cell. But can you give a bit more input on what the situation is ? like what do you mean by "I apply a sort the column"

Comment: The column (e.g. D) contains some values (number; e.g. ages). When I sort ascending the values, I need to change the background of D1 (header) in blue.

Comment: @colombo2003 your post is missing some data, please share a screen-shot of your excel sheet, which cells you want to color. Also you code attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can put this

> =SUMPRODUCT(-(A1:A10>=A2:A11))=-(A11< A10)

into a cell - where your range replaces A1:A10 - then use that as a trigger for your "Am I sorted query".

Comment: Always return FALSE (both if the values are sorted or not). - are not recognized. What is wrong?

Comment: This shows [Sorted](http://imgur.com/V0z2NY5) and this shows [Unsorted](http://imgur.com/i6JTetV). The [formula](http://imgur.com/GBRDKMr) is as shown.

Comment: Ok, but return FALSE if a cell in range is blank (or I delete it). How can I fix that?

Comment: If the cell in a range is blank or you delete it, it is no longer a sorted column. You now have two sorted ranges, split by a blank row.

Comment: And how to do this, when the position of a blank (or deleted) cell is variable?

Comment: I tried this: `code` Range("H1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter`code`

Comment: I tried this: `code` Range("H1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter`code`. And I want to attach a counting (variable x). If the value is odd, then the background color of cell is color 1 (filter on), else is color 2 (filter off). My problem is I don't know how to store the value of x and then use it after the macro is finish. Any idea? Thx